# How might this derivative be meant?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Consider $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, which might me decomposed as $y=u+v$ where $u\in\mathbb{R}^k, v\in\mathbb{R}^m, k+m=n$.

Moreover consider function $f(u,v)$ and $g(u.v)$.

How then might the expression
$$
\frac{\partial(f,g)}{\partial(u,v)}
$$
be meant, derivative of what? I am bit confused.

Comment: That may be a notation for the Jacobian matrix of $(f,g)$, or for its determinant. It would help a lot if you could provide the source where you found it.

Comment: I guess Jacobi matrix would make sense. Its from a lecture: After this, tthere is the expression $\lVert\frac{\partial (f,g)}{\partial (u,v)}\rVert$. I guess this only makes sense for the Jacobian.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly the partial derivative. It is defined as the Jacobian. It is used for transformation or change of variables in multiple integrals.
$$\frac{\partial (f,g)}{\partial (u,v)}=\begin{vmatrix}\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}   \frac{\partial f}{\partial v} \\
\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}  \frac{\partial g}{\partial v}  \end{vmatrix}$$

Comment: Ok, one further question please. Assume that $f'(0)=g'(0)=0$. Can we then say that, for some neighborhood of 0, small enough, we have $\lVert\frac{\partial (f,g)}{\partial (u,v)}\rVert\leq \delta$? I.e. which norm should be used?